# Can any RTF editors have highlighting of tags and display line numbers

Tags: mac, textedit

In MAC there is TextEdit used for viewing the RTF files.

Is it possible to have an editor(TextEdit or something else) for RTF files which highlights bracket when the cursor is placed either on the closed or open bracket. which highlights curly braces when the cursor is on either the open or closed curly brace, etc? (need highlighting for the textual content of the RTF file that a user will see and not the RTF source code)

Also, is it possible to enable line numbers in the rtf editor

Comment: https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/9558/Controls-and-Libraries/Rich-Text-Editor/Page-Layout/Line-Numbering

Comment: If online, see overleaf latex editor

Comment: Hi ankii, can you give an example. I copied my RTF file's source code(`Text edit preferences->open and save tab->tick display RTF file as RTF code instead of formatted text`) to latex editor but it did not compile. Also, My question was that the enclosing glyphs should be highlighted in RTF formatted text and not just in RTF source code